# Why can't I remove this Add-In?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, deployment

I've been deploying a SharePoint Add-In from Visual Studio 2015 to our O365 developer site.

For the past few days though, it has shown this deployment error:

> "Skipping the uninstall step because the SharePoint Add-in is in an
>   invalid state and cannot be uninstalled."

The Add-in is listed on the site's "**Site Contents**" page, but it is grayed out, and only has a "**Monitor**" action in it's menu.
[image: SharePoint Add-In Error]

How can I remove it? Or why won't SharePoint remove it? How do I get this to allow deployment? What could I be doing that would be interfering with this deployment?

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you need to verify that the user account that is
  performing this procedure is a member of the Site owners group.

If so **Return to classic SharePoint** link , now try click the ellipses (**...**) beside the application like image below then click remove:

[image]

Comment: I am the site owner and creator. And when I click "Remove" in Classic View, it says it is removing for a while, then says "Sorry we couldn't remove the app. Click to retry" And no matter how many times I retry, it never removes the app.

Comment: Ok @ZWhite i answered on the same probleme you can see it here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/225706/57592