# Add-in sharepoint deletion

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

The solution is not a permanent solution. I am able to delete it with the script provided. But i still cannot redeploy my solution from VisualStudio. Is there a way to get this working or do i need to keep deleting it with the script?

> I'm trying to deploy a Sharepoint online add-in that i created with
>   visual-studio 2015. After the first deploy i try to deploy it a second
>   time and i'm not able to do this.
>
> I get the error messages:
>
> > SharePoint Add-in is in an invalid state and cannot be uninstalled.
>
> When i couldn't uninstall the add-in that way i tried to delete it
>   from the browser "Site content" i could not see the option to do this.
>   Switching to the classic version i got the option. Still i'm not able
>   to delete it.
>
> If i click "Click to retry." it is not able to delete it.
>
> I'm Site Collection Administrators.
>
> What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem you need to remove your **SharePoint Add-In** by **PowerShell** so the following script demonstrate how to **Uninstall SharePoint Add-in in SharePoint Online**:

> **Note :** You must have [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)
>   installed on the system.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-ClientContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}


Function Uninstall-AppInstance([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[Guid]$AppInstanceId)
{
    $appInst = $Context.Web.GetAppInstanceById($AppInstanceId)
    $appInst.Uninstall()
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
 }



$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"
$AppInstanceid = New-Object Guid("XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")  #specify App Instance Id here

$context = Get-ClientContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Uninstall-AppInstance -Context $context -AppInstanceId $AppInstanceid
$context.Dispose()
```

**How to get App Instance Id**

1. Go to your **SharePoint Add-in** then try click the ellipses **(...)** beside the application like image below then click **DETAILS** :
   [image]

Once the detail page will be opened, **App Instance Id** could be grabbed from Url :

> /_layouts/15/AppMonitoringDetails.aspx?AppInstanceId=**XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX**

Comment: This i understand. But this gives me another question. Is it possible to create an app and deploy it to my SharePoint developer site? And redeploy it without using the script every time?

I forgot to mention it is a developer site of SharePoint online.

Comment: Normally you can just by redeploying your SharePoint Add-In by Visual Studio . The Error that you getting here is an **Expected Error** the only way to resolve it is executing this script to remove it then you can continue deployment normally.

Comment: I'm not able to let visualstudio delete it. Any ideas what could be the problem?
The script worked! (Thanks)

Comment: You are welcome If it's removed now try to redeploy it by visual studio again.

Comment: Yeah that works. The problem is that i always will need to run the script to delete the app.(i can not deploy a second time) This because i'm not able to delete the app from Visual Studio. 
Do you know if there is a solution so i can let visual studio uninstall the app and install the new version?