# "SharePoint Add-in is in an invalid state and cannot be uninstalled" from SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I cancelled (`CTRL` + `Break`) a SharePoint Add-in install from Visual Studio to a SharePoint Online development site because it was taking forever, and now get this message when attempting to re-deploy:

> SharePoint Add-in is in an invalid state and cannot be uninstalled

I can see the app on my site:

[image]

but don't believe it is actually being removed. When I click the ellipses, I get the option for details which gives me this info:

[image]

I tried removing it with Powershell using the script provided [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225683/add-in-sharepoint-deletion/225706#225706), but get:

> Another job exists for this app instance. Please retry after that job
>   is done.

[image]

Any good options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to wait for it to be removed from your site, it will take a few minutes (depending on the app). Then go to the trash and remove it from there. In the meantime close out of Visual Studios and reboot once the app is fully removed.

I haven't found any other solution to this problem besides time.

Comment: It took more than an hour to get cleared out, but you were right